# How to integrate AWS ECS with Okta

Tags: authorization, integration, saml, amazon-ecs, okta

I have a Spring boot application deployed in ECS and I am trying to integreate Okta with AWS ECS. I have 2 [ECS tasks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html#desired_count) due to which Okta validation is getting failed and showing me "Invalid Credentials". Its working when ECS tasks count is 1.

I have specified these parameter in properties file:
okta.oauth2.issuer, okta.oauth2.clientId, okta.oauth2.clientSecret, okta.oauth2.scopes, spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.redirect-uri

Below is the WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
@Profile({"qual", "cert", "prod"})
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/health")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Client()
                .and().oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

I am expecting my user to be successfully redirected to the application via Okta.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by enabling stickiness on load balancer